# How to access static methods in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do this, but it's not working like I'd expect.

(I'm using the AMD option)

```
//logger.ts
export class Logger {

    static log(message: string) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

//main.ts
import logger = module('services/logger');
logger.log("test"); //The property 'log' does not exist on value of type '"logger"'
logger.Logger.log(); //works
```

How do you do logger.log()?

Comment: that should work fine, I have similar code working ( perhaps the TS versioning solved it )

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can import classes directly, which allows you to have the usage you want.

```
// usage
import { Logger } from 'path/logger.ts'
Logger.Log();
```

And the definition stays the same.

```
// path/logger.ts
export class Logger {

    static Log() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**This answer was correct at time of posting. It is now deprecated. See [Dimitris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200215/1982385) for a better current solution.**

Using a class, you can't. You're always going to have to call `{module}.{class}.{function}`

But you can drop the class altogether and just call `{module}.{function}`:

```
// services/logger.ts
export function log(message:string){
 // do stuff
}

//main.ts
import logger = module('services/logger');
logger.log("test"); // Should work
```

Comment: The changes to how internal modules contribute to the type system aren't relevant here.

Comment: I wasn't clear if it was only internal modules that were changing. Thanks - I'll update.

Comment: I use this all the time for modules that are in fact singletons.

Comment: `The property 'log' does not exist on value of type "logger"`

Comment: If you export the function with no module wrapper? You must have some other bug in your code then.

Comment: ah, I was doing an explicit module wrapper, my bad

Comment: And no class as well - just export functions directly. Personally I prefer to wrap stuff up in a class and put up with the longer path, but then I come from an evil (C#) background, and don't know any better...

Comment: I would prefer to access through a class wrapper, but I don't want to have to do `module.class.function`,  I wanted the import to alias directly to the class.

Comment: This "import" statement doesn't really work for me: I'd use something like
```import * as logger from "./services/logger";```
 instead

Comment: As noted above @Starnutoditopo, this answer, from 2013, predates that syntax, and is deprecated in favour of Dimitris's up-to-date answer, below.