# Using bracket notation depending on input data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm in the process of optimizing some code in my library, however, I have a bit of an issue regarding why bracket notation isn't working when trying to call an imported class.

Parameter `type` accepts a string that is camelCased, such as: `myString`.
The parameter `data` can be anything.

```
import { foo } from './example';

export const find = (type: string, data: any) => {

// This next line effectively deletes the end of the string starting
// from the first capital letter.
    const f = type.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]+/, '');
    try {
        return [f][type](data);
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
};
```

this is what I expect it to look like if I was to visualize it using dot notation:

```
foo.fooBar(someRandomData)
```

This should call the static method `fooBar(data)` on the imported class `foo`,
however, I receive an error message:

```
TypeError: [f][type] is not a function
```

If I was to revert it back to my `if..else if` style, it works:

```
if (type.startsWith('foo')) return foo[type](data);
```

**How can I do what is desired above without getting the defined error message?**

*Thank you for your help in advance!*

> EDIT: This is an example I modified from already existing code, therefore, I fixed a few typos.
>
> EDIT #2: as per requested, the imported class `foo` looks like this:

```
export class foo{
static fooBar(data){
// Do stuff with data...
}
```

Comment: This is unclear to me.  What are you trying to accomplish with the `[f][type]` syntax?  Because what you're doing is creating an array containing `f`, then trying to access the property named `type` from said array, which is probably returning `undefined`, which is not a function.

Comment: First, you should probably not use "type" like this, considering it is a keyword. Second, type is a string, and you are trying to use it like an array of functions. Third, I don't see any reference to foo. How does foo relate to your code above? Could you also include the code for foo (the "example" file)?

Comment: Are you trying to say that if your `type` string is, for instance `'fooBar'`, then it should call `foo.bar(data)`?

Comment: the end goal is to access the correct imported class (because there's more than one class, but not in this example) so that is why I have it structured like `[class][method](data)` so I can *dynamically* call the correct class without having to do a bunch of `if` statements. Unless this isn't possible and I'm missing something..?

Comment: Here is a post about exporting a static class - from your code sample I don't see anything wrong with what you did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207593/how-to-access-static-methods-in-typescript.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what you are doing. You want to pass in a string that is really encoded with {className}{methodName} and passing data to it. Thus if you passed in fooBar as a value you would expect to have a class called 'foo' and a method in that class called 'fooBar' or maybe 'bar' that accepts the parameter 'data'.

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Jeremy. `type` is the input string *that is* the method of the class I want to access, and to keep it simple, I made the methods "extend" the name of the class.

For example: methods in the class `foo` would be: `fooBar(), fooBaz(), fooFun(), fooFar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end you need some reference to the classes or object to get started with. Here is a working example of how you could do this type of functionality, but you have start with a map of your class instances so you can get to them:

```
class foo {
    fooBar(data: any) { return { name: 'foo', data } };
}

class example {
    exampleFood(data: any) { return { name: 'example', data } };
}

var lookup: { [classes: string]: any; } = { };
lookup['foo'] = new foo();
lookup['example'] = new example();

const find = (encodedType: string, data: any) => {
    // This next line effectively deletes the end of the string starting
    // from the first capital letter.
    const f = encodedType.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]+/, '');
    try {

        return lookup[f][encodedType](data);
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
};

alert(JSON.stringify(find("fooBar", "Found you foo")));
alert(JSON.stringify(find("exampleFood", "Found you example")));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better option than using conditional statements as what you did was key/value the classes in `lookup`. I will be using a slightly modified version, so I thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you instead move over to using the nodeJS built-in [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

You can do something like:

```js
import * as EventEmitter from 'events';

import { foo } from './example';
import { bar } from './example2';

export const discordEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

discordEventEmitter.on('fooBar', foo.fooBar);
discordEventEmitter.on('fooToo', foo.fooToo);
discordEventEmitter.on('barBell', bar.barBell);
```

Then, when you want to fire an event, you can simply:

```js
discordEventEmitter.emit('fooBar', someData);
```

You can also simplify the event handler registration by writing:

```js
const fooProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(foo) as (keyof typeof foo)[];
fooProps.filter(k => typeof foo[k] === 'function').forEach(funcName => {
  discordEventEmitter.on(funcName, foo[funcName]);
});

const barProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bar) as (keyof typeof bar)[];
fooProps.filter(k => typeof bar[k] === 'function').forEach(funcName => {
  discordEventEmitter.on(funcName, bar[funcName]);
});
```